# Unable to retrieve data after adding fields to find() from mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have developed a code where I am able to retrieve all videos from filesystem whose file path is stored in mongo database:

```
app.get("/myvideos", function(request, result){

  database.collection("videos").find({}).toArray(function(error, videos){
    result.render("myvideos", {
      "isLogin": request.session.user_id ? true : false,
      "videos": videos
    });
  });
});
```

the above code is retreiving the files properly. However I wish to retrieve files of a particular user. My database schema is:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60914d02185c2a08add68fa2"),
        "user" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60914c73185c2a08add68fa0"),
            "name" : "Saumitra Lele",
            "image" : "",
            "subscribers" : 0
        },
        "filePath" : "public/videos/1620135170700-bigbuck.mp4",
        "thumbnail" : "public/thumbnails/1620135170700-Photo - Saumitra Lele.jpeg",
        "title" : "First video uploaded",
        "description" : "First video uploaded by Saumitra Lele",
        "tags" : "Saumitra Lele video",
        "category" : "Technology",
        "createdAt" : 1620135170708,
        "minutes" : 0,
        "seconds" : 32,
        "hours" : 0,
        "watch" : 1620135170708,
        "views" : 0,
        "playlist" : "",
        "likers" : [ ],
        "dislikers" : [ ],
        "comments" : [ ]
    }
```

However when I try to retrieve files of a particular user like so it doesn't work:

```
app.get("/myvideos", function(request, result){

  database.collection("videos").find({user:{_id:{$in:[user._id]}).toArray(function(error, videos){
    result.render("myvideos", {
      "isLogin": request.session.user_id ? true : false,
      "videos": videos
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try `{ "user._id": { $in: [user._id] } }` to match with exact field.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. This worked:

When user session got logged in, I created a new variable to store user name like so:

```
request.session.user_name = user.name
```

Then used the above for comparison as:

```
app.get("/myvideos", function(request, result){
  //var logInId = request.session.user_id;
  database.collection("videos").find({"user.name":request.session.user_name}).sort({
    "createdAt": -1
  }).toArray(function(error, videos){
    result.render("myvideos", {
      "isLogin": request.session.user_id ? true : false,
      "videos": videos
    });
  });
});
```

And the above worked properly!